# Google Apps Scripts functions stop working when script writer google account is deleted

Tags: google-apps-script

I wrote a few scripts/functions for a Google spreadsheet. On the spreadsheet there are a few buttons which I have created to run the functions when they are clicked. Some functions are normal functions and there was also simple triggers (onEdit etc.) Subsequently, I shared the spreadsheet to other users and they can click the buttons to run the functions correctly.

Later my email account was deleted as I no longer work there.

Other users told me that the buttons on the spreadsheet are no longer clickable - an error message appeared saying that the script function are not working (not the exact words, can't remember).

Is there a long term solution to this problem? I wrote the scripts so maybe in google scripts term I am the script owner (?) but my account is temporary so how do I ensure that the google scripts will still run for other users even if my account is deleted later?

Comment: It's better to use Google shared account..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In future what you can do is have your client (or employer) create a bound and/or standalone script from their account and have them share either the container document (spreadsheet, doc, slide, form etc.) or the stand-alone script with you.

This way they are the script owners and not yourself; you'll be able to modify the scripts as long as you've been granted edit access. For container-bound scripts make sure the client created the script by opening the script editor and saving the file (this ensures the script project is created under their account and not yours).

Alternatively, you can pass ownership of a document to another user, however in my experience passing ownership to another user is sometimes finicky. You're less likely to run into issues if your client owns the scripts to begin with.

Comment: To indicate to google scripts that the scripts I have written are created under the client's account, do they need to make copies of the scripts and save them, or just open the existing scripts and save them?

Comment: They'll need to create a new container-bound script or new stand-alone script and then copy/paste the code from the existing container or stand-alone script.

Answer (score 0):

## It's not quite plug and play but it works

Just get your own Google Account.  It will stay with you as long as you wish assuming Google is still around that long.  If you want to give them total control let them create a spreadsheet and share it with you and you copy all of the scripts into their spreadsheet and set it up for them and then it's their script.

Or you could put it in some sort repository and let them install the code themselves.

As an example here's a Note Taking Project that I did recently if you want to have a copy of it then go [here](https://sites.google.com/view/googlappsscript/time-stamped-notes).  Watch the videos and install the code and it's yours.